# Singleton Class factory

Tags: python, singleton, factory

to create Singleton u can do this:

```
class Klass:

    def __new__(cls, args):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
            cls.instance = Blah(args)
        return cls.instance
```

is there a way to create Singleton-classes on demand i.e:

```
  SingletonFactory('Klass1')
  obj11 = Klass1(args)
  obj12 = Klass1(args)
  #obj11 == obj12 ==> true

  SingletonFactory('Klass2')
  obj21 = Klass2(args)
  obj22 = Klass2(args)
  #obj21 == obj22 ==> true

  #obj11 == obj22 ==> false
```

the underlying class is still Blah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution,

```
def singleton(new_klass, klass): 

    def new(cls, *args, **kvargs):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
            cls.instance = klass(*args, **kvargs)
        return cls.instance


    globals()[new_klass] = type(new_klass, (object,), {'__new__' : new})
    #return type(new_klass, (object,), {'__new__' : new})


singleton('C1',Blah)
c1 = C1(10,10)
c2 = C1(10,10)

c1 == c2  #true

singleton('C2',Blah)
c3 = C2(10,10)


c1 == c3  #false
```